# How to force callback plot commands to go to desired figure window?

Tags: callback, focus, matlab-figure

I have a working `MATLAB` function which plots data in response to GUI buttons in the figure window, including a callback which starts/stops a loop to plot movie-like frames of sequential data.
The problem I would like to solve is: how can I set up two such windows, running with different datasets but based on the same code (functions, callbacks etc) without having the active plotting loop jump to whichever figure window happens to have focus?  That is, if I start one plot-movie, then click on the other window, the plotting takes place in this second window (and, only the GUI buttons in the original window can affect the plot).
What I'm hoping for is the equivalent of getting the figure window's `Figure Number` with, e.g., `gcbf` , and then adding a Property pair to my `imagesc` and `plot` commands to ensure the data are sent to the desired window.  It isn't clear to me what (if any) `Image Property` or `Chart Line Property` would do this.
Is what I want to do possible, and if so do I have to retrieve the `Axes` property from the figure and use that property to assign my data plots?  I don't require both plots to be actively updating simultaneously, but I do want to avoid the cross-window plotting that I'm dealing with now.

Comment: Your plotting commands should always specify the handle of an axes object to plot to. Relying on `gcf` or `gca` or similar commands is not a good idea for this exact reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to specify the `Parent` property when using `plot` or `imagesc` explicitly to ensure that the object is created in the appropriate place. You can do this using the `'Parent'` parameter / value  pair syntax or as the first input.

```
imagesc(data, 'Parent', hfigure)
imagesc(hfigure, data);
```

Personally I prefer the first option due to it being more explicit.

In general, you should always specify these parents to get a reliable result. While `gca` and `gcf` can  be handy, they are also completely dependent on where the user happens to click and which figure is active, so a change in user selection during the execution of your callback can change their values and result in unexpected behavior.

It seems like you're trying to run two instances of the same GUI.  If that's the case, then you should already have the handles to the `axes` objects so you should store them somewhere where they are accessible by the callbacks

```matlab
handles.hfigure = figure();
handles.haxes = axes('Parent', hfigure);
handles.hbutton = uicontrol('Parent', hfigure, 'Callback', @callback)

% Store all of the handles within the main figure's guidata
guidata(handles.hfigure, handles)

function callback(src, evnt)
    % Retrieve the stored handles
    handles = guidata(src);

    imagesc(rand(10), 'Parent', handles.haxes)
end
```

Or you can explicitly pass them to your callbacks

```matlab
hfigure = figure();
haxes = axes('Parent', hfigure);

hbutton = uicontrol('Parent', hfigure, 'Callback', @(s,e)callback(s, e, haxes));

function callback(src, evnt, haxes)
    imagesc(rand(10), 'Parent', haxes)
end
```

I personally prefer the second approach because I pass around *exactly* what is needed.

**Side Note**

Rather than calling `plot` and `imagesc` continuously from within your callback, you're going to get better performance creating the `image` or `plot`object in the intialization code of your GUI and then simply updating the `CData` or `XData` and `YData` properties from within the callback.

```matlab
hfigure = figure();
haxes = axes('Parent', hfigure);
himage = imagesc(NaN, 'Parent', haxes);
hbutton = uicontrol('Parent', hfigure, 'Callback', @(s,e)callback(s,e,himage))

function callback(src, evnt, himage)
    set(himage, 'CData', rand(10))
    drawnow
end
```

Comment: A special thanks for the optimization suggestion.  I'll implement that and the handle-passing code & report the results